# A unified story for building web UI and web APIs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am reading the asp dot net core documentation and here I read the following line.

> ASP.NET Core provides the following benefits: A unified story for building web UI and web APIs.

Can anybody explain to me what that means. Before core in Asp dot net 4.x version doesn't have it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place for explaination of subjects. If you have one specific question about a piece of code, just ask that.

Comment: @MarioVernari can you please give me some reference  link or rules link in support of your comment. I think I am writing the correct question in correct platform. I am confuse about asp dot net concept. and it is related to code. so please don't comments or vote down if you are not clear about the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you: you question deserve an answer (which I wouldn't able to give you). I write you about the improper topic here, due the clear policy of this tool: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
Please, don't see me as hostile: in fact, someone else downvoted you!

Comment: It's a marketing sentence, nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you get  this line form this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Based on my understanding, the asp.net core offers a cohesive and consistent approach to building both web user interfaces (UI) and web application programming interfaces (APIs).

Instead of using separate frameworks or approaches for UI and API development, ASP.NET Core allows developers to work with a unified set of tools and concepts.

For example, using the asp.net web api and vue.js.